# Using bootstrap product slider in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I'm trying to make a loop, but the result is not correct.

Here is the full code for the slider: [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/loschke/8489303#file-product-slider-html)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="well">
        <!-- Carousel
        ================================================== -->            
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide11">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>        
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide12">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide13">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide14">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide21">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>        
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide22">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide23">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide24">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide31">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>        
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide32">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide33">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/" alt="Slide34">
                              <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Product label</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">12,99 €</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Wishlist</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></a>

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>                
        </div><!-- End Carousel --> 
    </div><!-- End Well -->
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "is not correct"? are you loading the jquery and bootstrap javascript files? are you initializing the carousel as shown in the gist?

Comment: yes i do everything can you help me to make it work with wordpress give me the loop